# Bookmark page with redirect on iOS

Tags: html, ios, ipad, bookmarks

We have a webapp performing questionnaire like "scans". Entrance point is `/app`, which initializes a session to perform the scans. If "scan1" is part of the session, `/app` redirects to `/app/scan1`, otherwise you are redirected to `/app/scan2`.

If you hit `/app/scan1` directly, you won't perform `/app/scan2`. If you hit `/app/scan2`, you only perform that scan. We have a mobile version, iPad friendly, for our clients. This is responsive, so the url is the same, only the style changes.

Our client want to bookmark `/app` on his iPad, to make it easy to perform a so-called "quick scan" for his customers with both scan1 and scan2 involved. On Android, it is possible to create a bookmark, change the url of that bookmark and place the bookmark on your homescreen. However, iOS does not supply such feature. This makes it impossible to bookmark `/app`, as it automatically redirects and can't be bookmarked when you are on that page.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have implemented this now on the server. On `/app` a session is started, on `/app/scan1` and `/app/scan2` we check whether this session variable is set. If not, you will be redirected to `/app`, the session is started and you are redirected to `/app/scan1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create "bookmarks" on iOS, thus links that redirect to the app with an custom url-scheme like myapp://app/scan2 - then it's up to you to evaluate the string in your AppDelegate and show the corresponding view(controllers).